# how to code if this element activated the other element changes with html and css

Tags: html, css

I want to know if it's possible to click on an element and then change another element only using Html and CSS and if it is then how.

some thing like this ( btw this code doesn't work ) :

```
a:active div{
    background-color : blue;
}
```

Comment: so you are saying, you have two divs and when you click div1, div2 will change the background colour?

Comment: It will depend on the relative positioning/relationship betwen the two elements. Please put your HTML into the question so we can see the structure. If the two elements have no relationship then is is probably not possible but that again depends on what styling you want to apply so please be as specific as you can about that (i.e. is it just background-color that is to change?).

Comment: this link might be helpful: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-one-element-is-hovered-in-css/

Answer (score 1):

Without Javascript your options are rather limited.
You have to find a way to toggle the state by a click and be able to express those states in CSS.

Some option might be theese:

- using (hidden?) radiobuttons or checkboxes and using their `:checked` pseudo class in CSS
- using anchors and their pseudo classes (like you already attempted to do)

The problem here is that you have to put all your dynamic contents (the stuff you show/hide on click) inside or next to those toggling elements which might be inpractical.

My favorite is the `:target` pseudo class. When you open the URL "https://something.com#foobar" the element with the id "foobar" is the current target (if it exists). One limitation of this is that there is only one single target per document. You can control the target by clicking on anchors like this:

```css
.dynamic-content {
  display: none;
}

#first:target, #second:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="first" class="dynamic-content">
    First dynamic content
    <a href="#">Hide</a>
  </div>
  <div id="second" class="dynamic-content">
    Second dynamic content
    <a href="#">Hide</a>
  </div>
</div>

<a href="#first">Show first</a>
<a href="#second">Show second</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way ,I use :focus pseudo class. `div:focus a {}`